# Behaviour of :defined pseudo selector class

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, pseudo-class, custom-element

I had a script as follows

```js
const custElem = document.createElement('my-elem')
let res = custElem.matches(':defined');
console.log(`custElem.matches(':defined'): ${res}`);

res = custElem.matches(':not(:defined)');
console.log(`custElem.matches(':not(:defined)'): ${res}`);

customElements.define('my-elem', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor () { 
         super() 
    }
});

res = custElem.matches(':defined');
console.log(`After definition: custElem.matches(':defined'): ${res}`); // EXPECTED TRUE
```

I expected the last log to yield `true`. Why does `custElem` fail to match the `:defined` selector even after the definition of the custom element?

Comment: Because at the time `custElem` was initialized, the custom element typeof `my-elem` wasn't registered, and the element was created with a totally different constructor.

Comment: @Teemu Got it. So `:defined` matches against the [`custom Element State`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-element-custom-element-state) of the element upon creation and not whether it eventually matches against any defined element type.

Comment: @Teemu: You may post an answer now.